# lubridate converting midnight timestamp returns NA: how to fill missing timestamp

Tags: r, timestamp, lubridate

I have a data frame in R that I have imported from a CSV. The "time" format in the csv is "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" like so:

```
> head(btc_data)
                 time  btc_price
1 2017-08-27 22:50:00 4,389.6113
2 2017-08-27 22:51:00 4,389.0850
3 2017-08-27 22:52:00 4,388.8625
4 2017-08-27 22:53:00 4,389.7888
5 2017-08-27 22:56:00 4,389.9138
6 2017-08-27 22:57:00 4,390.1663
```

When I run `str(btc_data)` the time column comes back as a factor. So, I have converted this to datetime using the lubridate package as follows:

```
btc_data$time <- ymd_hms(as.character(btc_data$time))
```

The problem is the data collected at midnight (5 rows) fail to parse and return NA values like this (in the original data the timestamp is missing from these rows so `2017-08-29 00:00:00` is listed simply as `2017-08-29`) -

```
724 2017-08-28 23:59:00  4,439.3313
725 NA                   4,439.6588
726 2017-08-29 00:01:00  4,440.3050
```

Moreover, the second data frame is organized differently:

```
> str(eth_data)
'data.frame':   1081 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ time     : Factor w/ 1081 levels "8/28/17 16:19",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ eth_price: num  344 344 344 344 343 ...
```

When I try:

```
> eth_data$time <- mdy_hms(as.character(eth_data$time))
```

I get the following error:

> Warning message: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

**EDIT**: I have isolated the code issue that is causing the problem:

```
> btc_data[721:726,]
                   time  btc_price
721 2017-08-28 23:57:00 4,439.8163
722 2017-08-28 23:58:00 4,440.2363
723 2017-08-28 23:58:00 4,440.2363
724 2017-08-28 23:59:00 4,439.3313
725 2017-08-29          4,439.6588
726 2017-08-29 00:01:00 4,440.3050
```

So, each time the clock strikes midnight- the timestamp is not recorded. The CSV is being created via a data stream and is constantly growing, so this issue will continue to occur with each new day unless I can find a workaround. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include the rows that fail.

Comment: Please see my edits- I added the rows that fail, and the second df fails completely.

Comment: Show us the *text*, before lubridate has had a chance to mash it. Is it 00:00:00 or 24:00:00?

Comment: Also in your second example there's no "time" column in "eth_date". the columns are V1 and V2

Comment: Ah, well therein lies the issue I believe: it is blank and provides only the date (so for example `2017-08-28 00:00:00` is listed simply as `2017-08-28`

Comment: @Spacedman I edited the question to show the correct `str`

Comment: I've tried to and cannot reproduce your error. With those dates/times the output of `lubridate::ymd_hms` is correct. Even at midnight.

Comment: So for midnight  you are calling `ymd_hms` on something that is only a `ymd`, yes? That's why it fails. You should still show us the lines from the CSV. You'll have to handle those as an exception, possibly adding "00:00:00" to the string before calling `ymd_hms`.

Comment: @Spacedman: please see my edit- I could manually fix the csv but the problem will continue to occur.

Comment: Add the time to those elements manually: `with(df, ifelse(nchar(date) == 10, paste(date, "00:00:00"), date))`, then convert with `as.POSIXct`

Comment: @RichScriven can you post an answer to this question? I get the following error: `> with(btc_data, ifelse(nchar(btc_data$time) == 10, paste(btc_data$time, "00:00:00"), btc_data$time))
> Error in nchar(btc_data$time) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector`

Comment: Just do `btc_data$time <- as.character(btc_data$time)` on the line before that.  The answer below also shows this method, just with `grep` instead of `nchar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the '00:00:00' is completely missing in the original data to begin with, you can use grep to find those cases, then paste '00:00:00' before using the ymd_hms() or mdy_hm() function.

First case, where date/time format is 'YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS':

```
#Before
test <- fread("time,  btc_price
2017-08-28 23:57:00, 4439.8163
2017-08-28 23:58:00, 4440.2363
2017-08-28 23:58:00, 4440.2363
2017-08-28 23:59:00, 4439.3313
2017-08-29         , 4439.6588
2017-08-29 00:01:00, 4440.3050")

test$time[grep("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$",test$time)] <- paste(
  test$time[grep("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$",test$time)],"00:00:00")

#After
print(test)

                  time btc_price
1: 2017-08-28 23:57:00  4439.816
2: 2017-08-28 23:58:00  4440.236
3: 2017-08-28 23:58:00  4440.236
4: 2017-08-28 23:59:00  4439.331
5: 2017-08-29 00:00:00  4439.659
6: 2017-08-29 00:01:00  4440.305

#Now you can use ymd_hms(as.character(df$date)) as usual.
```

Second case, where date/time format is 'm/dd/yy HH:MM':

```
#Step 1 is to find/replace:
test <- fread("time,  btc_price
8/28/17 23:57, 4439.8163
8/28/17 23:57, 4440.2363
8/28/17 23:57, 4440.2363
8/28/17 23:57, 4439.3313
8/28/17      , 4439.6588
8/29/17 00:01, 4440.3050")

test$time[grep("[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}$",test$time)] <- paste(
  test$time[grep("[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}$",test$time)],"00:00"
)

print(test)
            time btc_price
1: 8/28/17 23:57  4439.816
2: 8/28/17 23:57  4440.236
3: 8/28/17 23:57  4440.236
4: 8/28/17 23:57  4439.331
5: 8/28/17 00:00  4439.659
6: 8/29/17 00:01  4440.305

#Step 2 is to adjust your mdy_hms() command; you need to leave off the 's':
#Ex. before:
mdy_hms(as.character("8/28/17 16:19"))
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 

#After
test <- c("8/28/17 16:19","8/28/17 00:00")
mdy_hm(as.character(test))
[1] "2017-08-28 16:19:00 UTC" "2017-08-28 00:00:00 UTC"
```

In general, it's also good practice to have numbers be formatted without commas in R; so 4,439.3313 should be 4439.3313. Otherwise, R might interpret that as a comma separation between columns.

Comment: Please see the edited question, the issue is not with the `btc_price` columns (which is being read fine) instead it is with the missing timestamp for midnight in the `date` column which is throwing the error.

Comment: I think youre still not understanding. for `2017-08-29` you have added the timestamp `00:00:00 UTC` but this is missing from the data if you look carefully at my question- and that is the underlying issue....how to insert 00:00:00 wherever the timestamp is missing from datetime.

Comment: @zsad512 - Now that you've clarified the question, I've edited my answer. See the updates above.

Comment: What about the second data frame where the dates are listed as `m/d/y`? Im still running into an error there: `All formats failed to parse`

Comment: I've now added the full example from start to end of how to do this.