# For Loops R: Feed result from grep(pattern) into For loop for multiple columns in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, lubridate

I would like to calculate with labvalues from certain (asynchronous) dates (120+). However, Lubridate does not allow both ymd and ymd_hms in the same column. Hence, I wrote a working grep which looks up the dates without time, and it adds 00:00:00 behind those. So i.e. 01-12-1998 becomes 01-12-1998 00:00 (based on this query: [lubridate converting midnight timestamp returns NA: how to fill missing timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015211/lubridate-converting-midnight-timestamp-returns-na-how-to-fill-missing-timestam))

Now I want to make a Forloop which automatically recognizes the eligeble columns (might alter in the future), and perform the time addition function.

I couldn't find the right documententation to tie all the functions below together. Would love to know where to find more info on this!

```
Data frame: Testset

ID  Lab_date1   Lab_date2        Lab_date3        Lab_date4
76  18/1/1982   26/01/1990       20/06/1990       15/11/1990
183 18/10/1982  24/04/1989       27/04/1989       02/04/1991
27  1/11/1983   18/10/1982 01:01 13/04/1983       31/10/1984
84  12-1-1983   12-1-1983 00:00  21-4-1983 15:10  22-3-1984 00:00
28  13-10-1989  13-1-1989 12:00  13-11-1991 14:11 19-11-1991 00:00
120 1-10-1982   14-7-1982 00:00  26-8-1986 00:00  26-8-1986 00:00
```

The function for altering the dates is, now programmed for Lab_date1

```
Testset$Lab_date1[grep("[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{4}$",Testset$Lab_date1)] <- paste(
  Testset$Lab_date1[grep("[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{4}$",Testset$Lab_date1)],"00:00:00")
```

Also, i wrote a grep (pattern) which returns the colnumbers of the lab dates, ie 2:4. Can this result be feeded into a a forloop with the function above?

```
dat_lab <- grep(pattern="Lab_date", 
         x=colnames(Testset))
```

I already tried this, but it didn't work

```
for(i in names(dat_lab)){
  y <- dat_lab[i]
  y[grep("[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{4}$",y)] <- paste(
    y[grep("[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{4}$",y)],"00:00:00")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` to change datetime in different formats.

```
library(dplyr)

Testset %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('Lab_date'), 
                lubridate::parse_date_time, c('dmY', 'dmY HM'))) -> Testset

Testset
#   ID  Lab_date1           Lab_date2           Lab_date3  Lab_date4
#1  76 1982-01-18 1990-01-26 00:00:00 1990-06-20 00:00:00 1990-11-15
#2 183 1982-10-18 1989-04-24 00:00:00 1989-04-27 00:00:00 1991-04-02
#3  27 1983-11-01 1982-10-18 01:01:00 1983-04-13 00:00:00 1984-10-31
#4  84 1983-01-12 1983-01-12 00:00:00 1983-04-21 15:10:00 1984-03-22
#5  28 1989-10-13 1989-01-13 12:00:00 1991-11-13 14:11:00 1991-11-19
#6 120 1982-10-01 1982-07-14 00:00:00 1986-08-26 00:00:00 1986-08-26
```

**data**

```
Testset <- structure(list(ID = c(76L, 183L, 27L, 84L, 28L, 120L), Lab_date1 = c("18/1/1982", 
"18/10/1982", "1/11/1983", "12-1-1983", "13-10-1989", "1-10-1982"
), Lab_date2 = c("26/01/1990", "24/04/1989", "18/10/1982 01:01", 
"12-1-1983 00:00", "13-1-1989 12:00", "14-7-1982 00:00"), Lab_date3 = c("20/06/1990", 
"27/04/1989", "13/04/1983", "21-4-1983 15:10", "13-11-1991 14:11", 
"26-8-1986 00:00"), Lab_date4 = c("15/11/1990", "02/04/1991", 
"31/10/1984", "22-3-1984 00:00", "19-11-1991 00:00", "26-8-1986 00:00"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the quick answer. When I run it however, it says
`no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: Did you change `df` to `Testset` according to the name of your data?

Comment: Ah, that was the first error. Then R gave `could not find function "accross"`, I fixed this through installing the `devtools` package. Thereafter, it was fixed. Thank you a lot, i've been struggling with this for over a week. 

Could you recommend any other reading on forloops and using these on other functions? I've got the most problems in how to state the "varying" `[i]` in the other functions, and expect to run into future trouble with this

Comment: I haven't read it myself but lot of people recommend [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) to start with. It seems to be a good read.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
library(dplyr)    
addFormats('%d/%m/%Y')
Testset %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with('Lab_date'), anytime))
#  ID  Lab_date1  Lab_date2  Lab_date3  Lab_date4
#1  76 1982-01-18 1990-01-26 1990-06-20 1990-11-15
#2 183 1982-10-18 1989-04-24 1989-04-27 1991-04-02
#3  27 1983-01-11 1982-10-18 1983-04-13 1984-10-31
#4  84 1983-01-12 1983-01-12 1983-04-21 1984-03-22
#5  28 1989-10-13 1989-01-13 1991-11-13 1991-11-19
#6 120 1982-01-10 1982-07-14 1986-08-26 1986-08-26
```